# One-to-many indexing

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree

I understand that postgres uses B tree /B+ Tree for indexing.I visualize each node in the tree as a key-value pair where the key represents the actual value being search for and the value is the location of that row in the disk.

This looks good for a one-to-one relationship.How does a BTree index for a one-to-many relation look like say a foreign key index - Each foreign key index can map to multiple rows in the child table.How does indexing happen here? A plain key-value pair based index doesnt seem to fit this case.

Comment: I think you are confusing a foreign key constraint with an index. Indexes are never across tables.

Answer (score 0):

What you described in a strict sense only requires a single `unique` index on the referenced table, in order to constrain its values to uniquely identify the particular row that's being referenced. The index on the other table B that has references pointing to A is helpful, but not necessary.

You can add it and it'll help you for example find all rows in B that point at a particular A. That second index will not have to be of `unique` type, unless you specifically want to allow only 1:1 links. I think this might be what you needed cleared up:

- All [`unique constraints`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) do require a `unique` index.
- To introduce a foreign key, you do need a `unique` constraint, and hence an index.
- Only the column that is being [referenced](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) requires the constraint. The column you reference it *from*, doesn't need it.
- Not all indexes have to be [`unique`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#id-1.9.3.69.6).